# How to pause an Animator with Mouseover?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I would like my `Animator` to pause when the mouse is not over it. For example, here it continues to update even when it's not moused-over:

```
Mouseover["not updating",
 {Animator[Dynamic[n], {0, 100, 1}], Dynamic[n]}]
```

[image]

Is there a simple trick to pause it (keeping n static) until it is moused-over again?

Comment: Can you give more specifics about what exactly you are trying to accomplish? There may be other solutions with manipulate or a user created animator which may or may not be acceptable depending on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

The `Animator` object has a lot of internal controls that are a bit difficult to access. Another solution, if you don't *need* an `Animator` object, is to define your own.

```
mouseSlider[max_,rate_] := DynamicModule[{running, i = 0}, Mouseover[
   running = False; "not running", running = True; 
   Dynamic[i += rate; {Slider[Mod[i, max], {0, max}], Mod[i, max]}]]]
```

[image: mouse slider]

Comment: It's a good approach, but there's no obvious way (at least that I can see) to enforce an exact animation rate :(

Comment: I included a rate in the definition of mouseSlider. You could also use a Pause command. If you give more details about what you're trying to accomplish, I may be able to tailor my answer to better suit your situation

Comment: Not my question, but just saying using an ++ increment has no connection to time

Comment: Are we looking at different things? You should see += rate (or += 0.01 in the animation)

Comment: Yes I’m talk about frame rates in real time

Comment: Ah I see, yeah that'd be tricky. Again I'm not sure what the OP is looking to use this for so I'm not sure what functionality is important to keep

Answer (score 3):

An extended comment. I tried with:

```
DynamicModule[{running = False, n = 0},
   EventHandler[
     Animator[Dynamic[n], {0, 100, 1},   AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[running]   ]
   , { "MouseEntered" :> FEPrivate`Set[running, True]
     , "MouseExited" :> FEPrivate`Set[running, False]   
     }
   ]
]
```

But at least on Win10 v12.1 the internal timer goes on and when on `MouseExited` and when it runs again it starts from the position it would have had without stopping.

**EDIT: The solution**

If we are less subtle it will work:

```
DynamicModule[{running = False, n = 0},
   EventHandler[
     Dynamic @ Animator[Dynamic[n], {0, 100, 1}, AnimationRunning -> running ]
   , { "MouseEntered" :> FEPrivate`Set[running, True]
     , "MouseExited" :> FEPrivate`Set[running, False]   
     }
   ]
]
```

It isn't completely FE-side anymore, evaluation of the whole `Animator[...]` goes back and forth, but at least it works.

Comment: I've been running in circles, can't figure out why it keeps going internally... any other approaches?

Comment: The scheduled task approach might be a bit heavy, especially if you try to make a grid of these things... are there no other dynamic magic tricks you know of to try here?

Comment: @user5601 See the edit, I am not happy about it but it more acceptable than tasks.

Comment: This is nice, but if I make 50 of them the FE does the spinny wheel... also TableView, how might you get this to work in a TableView?